# Typescript `Operator '+' cannot be applied to types` error occurs even though all cases are covered

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is the code.

```js
type Combinable = string | number;

function add(n: Combinable, b: Combinable) {
    if (typeof n === 'string'&& typeof b ==='string') {
        return n.toString() + b.toString();
    } else if (typeof n === 'string'&& typeof b ==='number') {
        return n.toString() + b.toString();
    } else if (typeof n === 'number'&& typeof b ==='string') {
        return n.toString() + b.toString();
    } else {
        // here raises error
        // Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Combinable' and 'Combinable'.ts(2365)
        return n + b;
    }
}

// But it works fine when I change "and" operator to "or" operator.
function add(n: Combinable, b: Combinable) {
    if (typeof n === 'string' || typeof b ==='string') {
        return n.toString() + b.toString();
    } else {
        return n + b;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I got the error on the last line `n + m`.

I thought it should work if I cover all cases, but the error still remains.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the type comparisons you're doing in the `if` statements with `&&` can't narrow down the type of any individual parameter.

After doing

```
if (typeof n === 'string' && typeof b ==='string') {
```

TS isn't smart enough to recognize that this means that either `n` or `b` is not a string: both `n` and `b` are still typed as `Combinable`.

Using `||`, on the other hand, makes it parseable, because it's absolutely certain that both `n` and `b` are not strings after that branch ends.

One way to fix it would be to nest the if/elses:

```
function add(n: Combinable, b: Combinable) {
    if (typeof n === 'string') {
        if (typeof b === 'string') {
            return n.toString() + b.toString();
        } else if (typeof b === 'number') {
            return n.toString() + b.toString();
        }
    } else if (typeof n === 'number') {
        if (typeof b === 'string') {
            return n.toString() + b.toString();
        } else {
            return n + b;
        }
    }
}
```

(can also use just `else` instead of `else if(cond)`, since there are no other alternatives)

Comment: Thank you first, I understand it as following, correct me if I am wrong plz. 
When I use `(A && B)` condition, TS doesn't know A evaluation result when it evaluates B condition. Hence the error raises.

When using `|` operator, neither `n` nor `b` are `string`, so both are evaluated as the remaining type `number`. That's why it doesn't complain. Am I right?

Comment: Not exactly - *Inside* the branch, they're narrowed properly, but after exiting the branch and going to an `else`, TS can't know *why* the branch wasn't taken - it doesn't take into consideration the two or three possible type combinations that produces that outcome. If you do `A && B`, you narrow down A and B inside that branch, but not outside it. If you do `A || B`, you narrow down A and B outside that branch, but not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Param = string | number;

function add(a: Param, b: Param) {
  if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
    return a + b;
  }
  return a.toString() + b.toString();
}

add(1, '2');
add(1, 2);
add('1', '2');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).